# Keyboard is not working properly

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

I installed 12.04 and it was working perfectly, but since yesterday I encountered a problem.

When I press left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, it doesn't respond but when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, it works as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and loses its own functioning.

Same with the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key it works as a <kbd>Pause Break</kbd> key and <kbd>Pause Break</kbd> key is working as a <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

<kbd>NumLock</kbd> key is working as a <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key.

After updating my OS, the problem is still happening. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore default keyboard layout settings. You can find it under `System`>`Keyboard`>`Layout Settings` .. `Restore Defaults` ..

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for help with this same notorious issue of key board and mouse not working and stumbled upon this answer for a 13.10 with the same problem but, it fixed my problem with 12.04

> The bug affects many people, its importance is set to "High", so we may expect that an official fix will be released soon. You can subscribe to notifications about this bug on launchpad.net, so that you receive an email when it's done.

Currently, a patch aimed at resolving this issue is being tested. By now it seems to work for most users, though certain problems remain. To install the patch, use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/1218322
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

A system reboot was needed in my case to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The **setxkbmap** command maps the keyboard to use the layout determined by
       the options specified on the command line.

```
setxkbmap [YOUR OPTIONS]
```

Comment: It would help to quote a manpage or give useful options for this command.